# Foreign key search fails in Rails 3

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-3

I am coding a small community in Rails 3 and I got two tables, Profiles and Contacts. When a user adds a friendship with another user it is saved in a table called Contacts which holds two columns; profile_id and friend_id.

Profile_id: This is where the users ID is saved
Friend_id: This is where the other users ID is saved

If a another user adds the user as a friend I want it to show up on the users home screen so that he can add the other user as well, but I only want it to show up if the user does not already have the other user as a friend.

I have tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work as I want it to.

```
@connections = Contact.where(["friend_id = ?", params[:profile_id]])

@notfriends = @connections.find_all {|profile| Contact.where(["profile_id = ? AND friend_id = ?", profile.friend_id, params[:profile_id]])}
```

Any ideas what is wrong? Is this the correct syntax?

**UPDATE**

So what I am looking to achieve is:

1. Get all contacts where the user is set as friend (friend_id).
2. Then I will would like to only get the contacts from the above query which the user does not already have as a friend (profile_id).

Comment: Did you use the right associations in the models 'Contacts' and 'Profiles'? (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Yes I think so, in Contacts I use: "belongs_to :profile" and in Profiles I use: "has_many :contacts". Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

In line 2 of your code params[:profile_id] and profile.friend_id are necessary the same...  since in your first query you search for entry where friend_id == params[:profile_id].

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have updated my question and I believe that my query is all wrong from what I would like to achieve. Could you please show me the correct query?